# How to change react-navigation/material-top-tabs tab lable dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I want change react-navigation/material-top-tabs tab name dynamically. Below is my code:

```
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

    let initialRootNameScreen = "ScreenA";
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarPosition= "top"
        backBehavior= "none"
        initialRouteName= {initialRootNameScreen}
        lazy= {false}
        removeClippedSubviews= {false}
        animationEnabled= {false}
        swipeEnabled= {false}

        tabBarOptions= {{
          upperCaseLabel: false,
          scrollEnabled: true,
          activeTintColor: Colors.white,
          inactiveTintColor: Colors.white_50,
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontFamily: Strings.APP_FONT,
          },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_BLUE_COLOR,
            height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 68 : 75,
          },
          indicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          },
          tabStyle: {
            width: viewportWidth / 3,
            alignSelf: "center",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="ScreenA"
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'ScreenA' }}
          children={() => (
            <ScreenA />
          )}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="ScreenB"
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'ScreenB' }}
          children={() => (
            <ScreenB />
          )}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="ScreenC"
          options={{ tabBarLabel: 'ScreenC' }}
          children={() => (
            <ScreenC />
          )}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

Need to change the tabBarLable dynamically. In earlier react navigation version it works fine by setParams lable name. But I haven't found any way in new versions.
Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks

Comment: Did you try storing the tabBarLabel in a state?

Comment: @strdr4605 ohh I missed that..let me try it. thanks